# Determine the indices of the element.values() list

Tags: python

Is there a way to obtain the indices of the `values()` list obtained from elements that have the typical attributes `items()`, `keys()`, and `values()`?

I have a list of custom objects that have matching ID strings (with those in `keys()` and `items()`), and would like to record the array element index locations of all items in a specific element.

Would the order of the `keys()` list always be the same as the `values()` list? For example, can I use the `keys()` list to find the indices like this?

```
idx = 0
for id in object.keys():
    custom_objects[id].vindex = idx
    idx += 1
```

My reason for wanting this is to be able to quickly iterate and assign the values of this specific object without searching/iterating for each entry.

Comment: _"Would the order of the `keys()` list always be the same as the `values()`?"_  probably, .  enumerating the `enumerate(ob.items())` items method will give index,  key, value.  Can you elaborate on how `custom_objectst[id].vindex` is set up?

Comment: I was not familiar with the `enumerate` function. That will come in useful. The custom objects are made up of a list of non-property class instances. `vindex` is just a normal `int` member. I'm not sure if that was what you wanted to know, but I can provide specific details if wanted. The objects have more members related to drawing and processing, but they are essentially an enumeration of a specific set of important properties. I actually set up these custom objects first, and use those to generate the properties dynamically (which you helped me with a while back).

Comment: I don't think its actually going to work at all. Unless I'm doing something wrong, it doesn't seem possible to modify an element's values by assigning directly to its `values()` or `items()`. When I assign a value to `object.values()[index]`, the value doesn't actually change. Does this mean its not possible to assign properties in a loop without using key-string lookup for each one?

Comment: Yes was about to mention, it's not a reference like `locals()`.  If you could elaborate would take some of the why? out of this.  Suggest using dictionaries, eg `dict(ob.items())`. Another issue with index is someone adding / deleting a custom prop will kill it.  `ob["_RNA_UI"]`  Can feed them into `type` can get many a prop as a dictionary with `to_dict()`

Comment: ...  how much quicker is it expected to be?

Comment: These properties (for the window) are all generated at startup, and would not change. When the window opens, custom properties and data from the active scene element are used to assign the values to these window properties. This is where I am iterating through them. There are also a couple of other situations where I want to iterate and assign them all, such as to assign to their defaults, or to another element's data. So I was just trying to find a way to do this without using key-string IDs inside the loop. Not really looking for a speed boost - just trying to avoid wasting processing time.